# Best way to make @types packages visible in an nx workspace

Tags: nrwl-nx

### Background

I'm trying to remove [resize-observer-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resize-observer-polyfill) from an nx workspace that I'm working on because it's natively supported in the browsers that we are targeting. Once I removed the polyfill, I needed to add [@types/resize-observer-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/resize-observer-browser) because the workspace currently uses `typescript@4.0.5` and my understanding is that TypeScript does not have a "native" type for `ResizeObserver` until [v4.2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#libdts-updates) which I'd love to update to, but can't atm.

### Problem

In order to make TypeScript happy, it seems like I have to go in and manually add `"resize-observer-browser"` to individual `tsconfig` `compilerOptions.types` entries. This didn't seem that bad to me at first. I just updated the `tsconfig.lib.json` file of the libraries that happened to utilize `ResizeObserver`. However, I soon realized I needed to also add it to the `tsconfig.spec.json` of the libraries so that the unit tests could run, and then I also needed to add it to the `tsconfig.app.json` of any applications that happened to import those libraries.

### Question

Is there an easier way in an nx workspace to handle this sort of problem?

I think that I could remove the default `types` overrides in each of the `tsconfig` files, since that would let TypeScript just utilize everything that exists under `node_modules/@types` when compiling. I didn't want to take that path since I assume there is a good reason for the default nx library/app generators to add the `types` override (I assume it's to force you to be explicit and not accidentally get away with accidental imports of test code from business logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs seem to recommend against this for `@types` packages, but `/// <reference types="..." />` (e.g. `/// <reference types="resize-observer-browser" />`) can be also be used to include types, and might be easier to manage if the type is only used in a few places.

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html#-reference-types-